# How to properly use in_stock in Amazon Forecast related time series

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-forecast

I'm trying to understand the data required for Amazon Forecast to create a demand forecast using my historical sales data. I've read through the documentation many times. I am still confused as to how the "in_stock" field in a related time series is supposed to function. Here is a link to the description of the "in_stock" field I am referring to:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/retail-domain.html#related-time-series-type-retail-domain

It says:

> The following fields are optional and might be useful in improving
>   forecast results:
>
> - in_stock (integer; 1=true, 0=false) – A flag that specifies whether the item is in stock.

What exactly is this field meant to indicate? Is it only meant to be set to 0 when the number of sales is 0? In other words, if the number of sales for a given day is 0, and in_stock is set to 0, then the system knows the sales were 0 because the product was not available, not because there was no demand.

What if a product goes out of stock halfway through the day. Would that be a case where you might have in_stock = 0 but also have sales on that day?

I am also confused how this in_stock field comes into play when in another piece of their documentation:

https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/time-series-forecasting-principles-amazon-forecast.pdf?did=wp_card&trk=wp_card

On page 10, they say:

> In the retail case study, the information that a retailer sold zero
>   units of an available item differs from the information that zero
>   units of an unavailable item are sold either in the periods outside
>   its existence, e.g. before its launch or after its deprecation, or in
>   periods within its existence, e.g. partially out of stock, or when
>   there was no sales data recorded for this time range. The default zero
>   filling is applicable in this former case. In the latter, even though
>   the corresponding target value is typically zero, there is additional
>   information conveyed in the value being marked as missing. You must
>   preserve the information that there was missing data and not discard
>   this information (see the following example for an illustration why
>   keeping the information is important). To encode a value that does not
>   represent zero sales of an available product as truly missing, Amazon
>   Forecast allows the user to specify the filling type for middle fill
>   and back fill in the FeaturizationMethodParameters key of the
>   FeaturizationConfig parameter of the create_predictor API. To mark a
>   value as truly missing, the fill type for these parameters should be
>   set to NaN. Unlike for zero filling, the values encoded with NaN are
>   treated as truly missing, and not used in the metrics evaluation
>   component.

This seems to indicate that when a product is out of stock and there are no sales, those rows should be marked as `NaN`, which effectively removes those rows from the dataset.

I suppose my questions boils down to:

1. What is the difference between a day with 0 sales and in_stock = 0 vs a day with sales = NaN, which effectively removes that day from the dataset?
2. What do you do when a product goes out of stock partway through the day? Can in_stock = 0 and still have sales data for a given day?

Answer (score 1):

1. The difference is that with in_stock your model includes more information allowing you to do projections based on in_stock into the future. It's better to use in_stock as opposed to sales = NaN as long as you have the historical data.
2. If you require in_stock to be represented as a partial day, your time series will need to be more granular. If you can't achieve more granularity you should be able to specify sales > 0 and in_stock = 0, all this will do is train the model, for that Id, that when an item is out of stock a certain amount of sales are made hence it is better to have a more granular time series.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case the recommendation would be to specify sales = 'NaN' in the TARGET_TIME_SERIES when a particular product is unavailable / out-of-stock. This is as per the approach outlined in: https://d1.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/time-series-forecasting-principles-amazon-forecast.pdf. The example in Figure 6 (on page 11) elaborates on this further. For cases where a product goes out of stock part way through the day, the sales value should be specified.

It is also worth noting that at the time of this writing, RELATED_TIME_SERIES in Amazon Forecast requires the last timestamp for every item in the related time series dataset must be on or after the last timestamp in the target time series plus the user-designated forecast window (called the forecast horizon). See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/forecast/latest/dg/related-time-series-datasets.html for additional details.

Hope this helps.